# How to use Console.app to view debug-level logs from os_log from an iOS app running in the Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, oslog

This is a question about how to use Apple's Unified Logging framework, also known as "os_log", the function you call from Swift.

Specifically, I want to know if it is possible:

1. to view logs in Console.app (*not with the `log` command line tool*) ...
2. to see `debug`-level logs (*not just `info`-level logs*) ...
3. for an iOS app running in the Simulator (*not just running on a device*).

You cannot do this just by running Console.app, pointing at the Simulator, and selecting *Action / Include Debug Message*, which is the obvious thing to do.

[This article](https://www.iosdev.recipes/simulator/os_log/) suggests that `debug`-level logs don't show up because "the 'system' log level is set to `info`" but I can't find a discussion anywhere that explains what that means.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug in the Console app when dealing with the simulator: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82736

I believe a Radar has been logged: rdar://47667447